# How do you add a condition for invalid/empty input to a Contact Form using FormSpree?

Tags: reactjs, forms, next.js

I am using [Formspree](https://formspree.io/) to make a simple Contact form in my NextJS website. Formspree provides the following sample code snippet for React:

```
// Make sure to run npm install @formspree/react
// For more help visit https://formspr.ee/react-help
import React from 'react';
import { useForm, ValidationError } from '@formspree/react';
function ContactForm() {
  const [state, handleSubmit] = useForm("YOUR_FORMSPREE_UNIQUE_KEY");
  if (state.succeeded) {
      return <p>Thanks for joining!</p>;
  }
  return (
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
      <label htmlFor="email">
        Email Address
      </label>
      <input
        id="email"
        type="email" 
        name="email"
      />
      <ValidationError 
        prefix="Email" 
        field="email"
        errors={state.errors}
      />
      <textarea
        id="message"
        name="message"
      />
      <ValidationError 
        prefix="Message" 
        field="message"
        errors={state.errors}
      />
      <button type="submit" disabled={state.submitting}>
        Submit
      </button>
    </form>
  );
}
function App() {
  return (
    <ContactForm />
  );
}
export default App;
```

Trouble is, if a user submits the form with empty fields, it still gets submitted. I searched the web, looked up some formspree implementations on YT and checked their website. But didn't find a solution on how to prevent a user from submitting with empty fields.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented the simplest solution I could think of:

1. I modified the `onSubmit` of the form in the following way, adding a switch statement:

   `onSubmit = { (email.length>0 && message.length > 0) ? handleSubmit : errorAlert}`
2. Added errorAlert function as follows:

   `function errorAlert() {
   alert("cannot leave any field blank.")
   }`

This way, using a switch statement one can add whatever conditions and failsafes one wishes to add to the form submission text fields.

Answer (score 0):

Try this method:

```
import { useForm } from "@formspree/react";
function ContactForm() {
    const [state, handleSubmit] = useForm("your-form-id");

    const manageSubmit = (e) => {
        // other logic or error checking logic here
        handleSubmit(e); // call the handleSubmit function with event (e)
    }

    if (state.succeeded) {
        return <p>Thanks for joining!</p>;
    }

    return <form onSubmit={manageSubmit}></form>
}
```